CSV file shows empty line or patial of content
I wrote a python file to collect some server certificate info and save in a csv file.
Everything works fine except the display when open the csv file.
As you can see the Cert Name field is either empty or only show part of cert name.
But when I click each cell, the full name is there.
I copied the cert name to a notepad and it shows a quotation mark in front of each line like this "tomcat/tomcat.pem.
Is there a way to display those cert name properly?
Prefer to do it within python since we have multiple servers for this job.

The [open] double quote will infer a text string, and commas are not taken as separators (they are now part of the string) until the next [close] double quote. The cell will hold all data from the first double quote to the next or to the end of the file or to the capacity of the cell. If the double quote(s) are undesirable then remove them in your python script.

Show us the text content of the CSV file, not an image of the problem, and the minimal Python code used to generate it (see [mcve]) guidelines).

I found it is just the Excel display issue.
It did not display properly if I only change the width of the cell.
Once I increase the height of the cell, content is displayed properly.
